# Assigning Azure service roles as a Service Principal

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, terraform

I have created a Service Principal with the following access:

- `Contributor` role on subscription
- `Global administrator` role on AAD tenant
- Consented Microsoft Graph API permissions:

  - Group.Read.All
  - User.Read.All

While authenticated with this SP, I am trying to assign Azure service roles to AAD groups. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_account_admin" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.my_storage.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.my_group.object_id
}
```

When trying to apply this, Terraform throws an authorisation error from Azure:

> The client '...' with object id '...' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/...' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I am able to create this resource with my user Azure account, which has the `Owner` role. Do I need to elevate my Service Principal to `Owner` -- that seems a bit dangerous -- or is there a more specific way of resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the `Contributor` role does not include `authorization` related permissions like role assignments.

To fix this error, either assign `Owner` role to your Service Principal or add [`User Access Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) role to the Service Principal.